# HTML/JS Carousel without using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been trying to build a custom slider and I'm currently stuck. So at the moment it moves forward using css to animate. However I'm able to go backward but without an animation. I believe I need to loop through the slides and perhaps try a difference approach but i'm currently struggling.

I've tired to set a the current_slide by adding a .active class to the first article on load and then using the jquery index function with no luck. Also I'm unfamiliar with the 'props:' syntax and Google wasn't very helpful. Once again any help would be appreciated

```js
"use strict";

(function() {

 var carouselWidth = $('.carousel-cells').width();
 var Carousel = {
  props:{
   current_slide:null,
   total_slides:null
  },
  init:function(){
   //ADD INITIALIZER CODE HERE
   Carousel.bindEvents();
   $('.carousel-cells').css({marginLeft: -carouselWidth});
   $('article:first-child').addClass("show");
  },
  bindEvents:function(){
   $(".carousel-next").on("click",function(){
    Carousel.next();
   });
   $(".carousel-prev").on("click",function(){
    Carousel.previous();
   });
   $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key===37) Carousel.previous();
    if (key===39) Carousel.next();
   });
  },
  next:function(){
   //ADD NEXT CODE HERE
   Carousel.update();
   $('article:first-child').appendTo('.carousel-cells');
   $('article:first-child').addClass("show");
  },
  previous:function(){
   //ADD PREVIOUS CODE HERE
   Carousel.update();
   $('article:last-child').prependTo('.carousel-cells');
   $('article:last-child').addClass("show-prev");
   $('article:first-child').addClass("margin-reset");
  },
  update:function(){
   //ADD UPDATE CODE HERE
   $('article').removeClass("show");
   $('article').removeClass("show-prev");
  }
 }
 $(function(){
  Carousel.init();
 })

})(window);
```

```css
body{
 background-color:#e2e2e2;
}
header{
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#ccc;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:2;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
header h2 {
 font-size: 28px;
 margin: 13px 10px;
}
header nav  {
 float: right;
}
header nav ul {
 margin: 10px 10px;
}
header nav li {
 background-color: #e2e2e2;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
}

.page-content{
 padding-top:50px;
}

.page-content .main-carousel{
 width:100vw;
 height:400px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next,
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 padding:20px;
 background-color:rgba(200,200,200,1);
 cursor:pointer;
 margin-top:-25px;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next{
 right:0;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev{
 left:0;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells {
 width:99999px;
 height:100%;
 margin-left: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
 transition: 1s all ease;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells .show {
 margin-left: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: .6s all ease-in;
 transition: .6s all ease;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article .show {
 margin-left: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: .6s all ease-in;
 transition: .6s all ease;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article .margin-reset {
 margin-left: 100%;
 display: none;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article .show-prev {
 margin-left: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: .6s all ease-in;
 transition: .6s all ease;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article{
 width:100vw;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-transition: .8s all ease-in;
 transition: .8s all ease-in;
 background-image: url("../img/slide-background.jpg");
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article + article {
 margin-left: 100%;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article .slide-text {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.column-content {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 padding: 33px 18px 40px;
}
.column-content h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.three-columns {
 column-count: 4;
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
 column-gap: 55px;
 -webkit-column-gap: 55px;
 column-fill: balance;
}

.three-columns .list-block {
 break-inside: avoid;
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.three-columns h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
}

.three-columns .list-block h3 {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.three-columns .list-block ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .three-columns {
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
 }
 .three-columns .list-block {
  break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
 }
 .three-columns .list-block ul {
  min-height: 50px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/css/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/css/base.css" />

  <script src="inc/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="inc/js/base.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
     <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="page-content">
   <section class="main-carousel">
    <div class="carousel-next">&gt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-prev">&lt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-cells">
     <article>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h1>Slide One</h1>
       <p>A slide about sliding slides.</p>
      </div>
     </article>
     <article>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h1>Slide Two</h1>
       <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
      </div>
     </article>
     <article>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h1>Slide Three</h1>
       <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
      </div>
     </article>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section class="column-content">
    <h1>Three Columns</h1>
    <div class="three-columns">
     <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
     </aside>
     <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
     </aside>
     <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
     </aside>
     <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
       <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
     </aside>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YFgAM/

```
$('.block-13 .show-more.prev').click(function () {

    var last = $('.block-13 .list li:last-child');

    last.remove();

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').prepend(last);

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').css({
        right: '+=' + width
    });

    $('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        right: '-=' + width
    });

});
```

You can prepend the element (in your case, it's '.carousel-prev') before animation begins.